# React native how to wrap content view

Tags: react-native

I'm pretty new with RN, is there anyway to wrap the content of the view, similar to Android. In Android I can adjust, Height: 'wrap-content', but somehow in RN, I can't do any wrap content.

It's either I set the height of the view, or just flex, but still not wrap the view.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can set the parent to wrap child component like this.

> alignSelf: 'baseline'

```
<View style={{ alignSelf:'baseline'}}>
  <Text>Child Content</Text>
</View>
```

Wrap child content horizontally.

Comment: Being a bit lazy, but could someone explain why this works?

Comment: View is by default a block element. Aligning self to baseline makes the component act as an inline element. Thus taking up only the space required by the child components.

Comment: `alignSelf:'center'` worked also

Answer (score 24):

In the case of `flexDirection: "row"`, you should use `flexWrap: "wrap"` to **wrap** the items inside.

Answer (score 7):

## Solution 1:

You can use `alignSelf: 'baseline'` tp set the parent to wrap child component like this

```
<View style={{ alignSelf:'baseline'}}>
  <Text>Child</Text>
</View>
```

## Solution 2:

In the case of `flexDirection: "row"`, you should use `flexWrap: "wrap"` to `wrap` the items inside the view.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
  <Text>Child</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 4):

If the content is vertical it should wrap by default;
If the content is horizontal, things get tricky...
What worked for me was putting the view container inside another view:

```
<View style={{alignItems: "center"}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
        <Image/><Text/>
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score -3):

Views wrap their content by default if 'flex' attribute is not set.

If you need the view to fill parent width or height set 'alignSelf' attribute to "stretch".

Comment: When flex is not set, the view does not wrap all of its children, it shrinks and children become overlapped so that the entire layout is not visible.